# When I am centering jQuery Accordion it is transferring the next paragraph to it's upper side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to center a accordion. At first I tried with `margin: auto;` but it was not centered. Then I tried with `left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` and it worked but I found something wrong. There was a paragraph after accordion and it was placed before the accordion.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.area {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0;
}


/* ========================== Accordion ==================================== */

.accordion {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>jQuery UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p class="area">---------------------------- Accordion ----------------------------</p>
  <div class="accordion">
    <h2 class="accordion-title">Web Design</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi neque laborum sed repellat! Nemo dignissimos aliquid facilis aspernatur error neque repellat reiciendis praesentium eligendi iste perspiciatis quia ut voluptatibus, unde id, eaque libero
        corporis officia explicabo, doloremque vero culpa labore! Quae amet impedit maxime aspernatur nemo voluptates repudiandae minus, laborum dolores aperiam facilis, dolor ipsa tempore, illum quis possimus? Sit omnis minima velit recusandae debitis
        reiciendis commodi nulla perferendis est dolore consectetur porro, aut quam quidem quod aperiam, maxime, totam odit laboriosam tempore facere rem. Labore ex asperiores animi, perferendis sequi error! Ad iste exercitationem voluptate sint sapiente
        ipsum? A!</p>
    </div>

    <h2 class="accordion-title">Web Development</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi neque laborum sed repellat! Nemo dignissimos aliquid facilis aspernatur error neque repellat reiciendis praesentium eligendi iste perspiciatis quia ut voluptatibus, unde id, eaque libero
        corporis officia explicabo, doloremque vero culpa labore! Quae amet impedit maxime aspernatur nemo voluptates repudiandae minus, laborum dolores aperiam facilis, dolor ipsa tempore, illum quis possimus? Sit omnis minima velit recusandae debitis
        reiciendis commodi nulla perferendis est dolore consectetur porro, aut quam quidem quod aperiam, maxime, totam odit laboriosam tempore facere rem. Labore ex asperiores animi, perferendis sequi error! Ad iste exercitationem voluptate sint sapiente
        ipsum? A!</p>
    </div>

    <h2 class="accordion-title">Programming</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi neque laborum sed repellat! Nemo dignissimos aliquid facilis aspernatur error neque repellat reiciendis praesentium eligendi iste perspiciatis quia ut voluptatibus, unde id, eaque libero
        corporis officia explicabo, doloremque vero culpa labore! Quae amet impedit maxime aspernatur nemo voluptates repudiandae minus, laborum dolores aperiam facilis, dolor ipsa tempore, illum quis possimus? Sit omnis minima velit recusandae debitis
        reiciendis commodi nulla perferendis est dolore consectetur porro, aut quam quidem quod aperiam, maxime, totam odit laboriosam tempore facere rem. Labore ex asperiores animi, perferendis sequi error! Ad iste exercitationem voluptate sint sapiente
        ipsum? A!</p>
    </div>

    <h2 class="accordion-title">Wordpress Development</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi neque laborum sed repellat! Nemo dignissimos aliquid facilis aspernatur error neque repellat reiciendis praesentium eligendi iste perspiciatis quia ut voluptatibus, unde id, eaque libero
        corporis officia explicabo, doloremque vero culpa labore! Quae amet impedit maxime aspernatur nemo voluptates repudiandae minus, laborum dolores aperiam facilis, dolor ipsa tempore, illum quis possimus? Sit omnis minima velit recusandae debitis
        reiciendis commodi nulla perferendis est dolore consectetur porro, aut quam quidem quod aperiam, maxime, totam odit laboriosam tempore facere rem. Labore ex asperiores animi, perferendis sequi error! Ad iste exercitationem voluptate sint sapiente
        ipsum? A!</p>
    </div>

    <h2 class="accordion-title">Digital Marketing</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi neque laborum sed repellat! Nemo dignissimos aliquid facilis aspernatur error neque repellat reiciendis praesentium eligendi iste perspiciatis quia ut voluptatibus, unde id, eaque libero
        corporis officia explicabo, doloremque vero culpa labore! Quae amet impedit maxime aspernatur nemo voluptates repudiandae minus, laborum dolores aperiam facilis, dolor ipsa tempore, illum quis possimus? Sit omnis minima velit recusandae debitis
        reiciendis commodi nulla perferendis est dolore consectetur porro, aut quam quidem quod aperiam, maxime, totam odit laboriosam tempore facere rem. Labore ex asperiores animi, perferendis sequi error! Ad iste exercitationem voluptate sint sapiente
        ipsum? A!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="area">----------------------------------------------------------------------</p>


  <!-- ------------------------- JavaScript Start ---------------------------------------- -->
  <script src="./jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="./jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // --------------------------- Accordion ------------------------------------
      $(".accordion").accordion();
    });
  </script>
  <!-- ------------------------- JavaScript End ---------------------------------------- -->
</body>

</html>
```

There was a paragraph before and after the accordion. But after centering they took place at the top side.

I downloaded the jQuery and the jQuery ui file. jQuery version: 3.6.0 and jQuery ui version: 1.12.1.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css flex. It will resolve your problem. All you have to do is to wrap the accordian div with another div.

Like,

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="accordion">
   .
   .
   .
 </div>
<div>
```

in css

```
.wrapper{
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.accordian{
  width: 70%;
}
```

Please remove all other css properties from accordian class. It should work.